# Cannot find netbeans output directory via remote programming C

Tags: c, linux, netbeans, raspberry-pi

When I run my C project via netbeans deploying remotely to my Raspberry Pi, this is the path in the output console:

`/root/.netbeans/remote/192.168.1.132/ian-pc-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/Ian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/gpsComplete`

However, on my RPi when I go to root, the .netbeans folder isnt there.

I have tried cd /.netbeans, but it says the directory does not exist.

I have done a `find` on type directory for the name `"*gpsComplete*"` and `"*netbeans*"` searching from root, but it again does not find either of those directories.

I am at a loss, I need to find the executable file to run, but I dont know where it is. I do have the folder locally on my system for the project files, but it does not have the `dist` folder where any executables would be.

Comment: did you try `cd /root/.netbeans`?

Comment: @Olaf tried that too, however it still doesn't exist, in that case it says `root does not exist`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Seems like you are logged in as the root user. You should log in as a normal user and try again.